# Does Dark Wake turn on the backlight, but with all pixels black, on an iMac?

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, screen

Sometimes, when I wake up in the middle of the night, I find my iMac's screen suddenly come on, but with all pixels black.

On one occasion, I also found color bars like

[image]

at the top-left corner of the screen, with the rest of the screen black.

Is this normal? It feels eerie when the screen turns on suddenly in the middle of the night, but displays only black.

Power Nap was enabled.

Comment: Did you solve this? My 5k iMac is doing the same thing.

Comment: It no longer happens. I did nothing beyond updating macOS and reseting NVRAM and SMC.